# Tabla con header fijo con html y css puro

Tags: html, css, html5, table

Bueno lo trato de hacer es una tabla con un header estático y su body con scroll horizontal, en su esencia lo he logrado, pero el ancho de cada columna es similar, el ancho de la primera columna **ID,Precio,Stock** debería ser mas pequeño (adaptándose a su contenido, que simplemente son máximo 4 dígitos).

Ayúdenme con eso por favor, he pensado dando un tamaño solo a las celdas que deben ser mas pequeñas **(ID,Precio,Stock)**, pero creo que estaría mal.

También quisiera que para distintas pantallas se adaptara la altura, pero no puedo hacerlo con porcentajes (lo he tratado pero no he podido, porque creo que debe ser una altura especificada en pixeles). Seria necesario usar media querys?

```css
* {
  font-family: arial;
}
.header-fixed {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  /*la que necesites*/
  max-height: 80vh;
  /*la que necesites*/
  overflow: auto;
}

.header-fixed thead,
.header-fixed tbody {
  display: block;
}

.header-fixed thead {
  position: sticky;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
}

.header-fixed thead tr > th {
 background: #212529;
 border-color: #32383e;
 color: #fff;
 margin: auto;
 /*padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;*/
}

.header-fixed tr {
  display: flex;
}

.header-fixed th,
.header-fixed td {
  min-width: 150px;
  /*La que necesites*/
  max-width: 150px;
  /*La que necesites*/
  padding: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<table class="header-fixed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope='col' class="id">ID</th>
      <th scope='col'>Producto</th>
      <th scope='col'>Precio</th>
      <th scope='col'>Stock</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>1</th>
      <td>Producto 1</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>13</th>
      <td>Producto 2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>21</th>
      <td>Producto 3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>...</th>
      <td>Producto ...</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Podrías usar la unidad de medida **4em** que equivaldría al espacio que ocupan cuatro letras **M**.

Comment: El problema que noto es que le pusiste una altura fija de **100px** a la tabla entera con el estilo de la clase **header-fixed**.

Comment: Es que debo ponerle una altura fija, o sino el scroll no funcionara. se puede poner con porcentajes? He intentado pero me ha fallado

Comment: Como dijistes que modificara el ancho de las columnas? Estoy tratando, pero... (.header-fixed thead tr > th:nth-child(1) {
 width: 2em;
})

Comment: Ahí publiqué el código. El scroll funciona cuando se excede el **max-height**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podés usar la unidad de medida `em` para que las celdas tengan un ancho mínimo de cuatro letras **M** y borrar la parte en la que se establece una altura fija a la tabla en `.header-fixed { ... height: 10px; ...}`. En el ejemplo uso una altura máxima de `100%` para que dependa del tamaño del elemento padre, pero si la estructura de la página te lo permite, podés usar **vh**.

Además agregué esos tres estilos en `*{}` que suelen evitar desajustes molestos en las mediciones.

```css
    * {
    font-family: arial;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  body{
    height: 100vh;
  }
  .header-fixed {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  .header-fixed thead,
  .header-fixed tbody {
    display: block;
  }
  .header-fixed thead {
    position: sticky;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .header-fixed thead tr > th {
   background: #212529;
   border-color: #32383e;
   color: #fff;
   margin: auto;
  }
  .header-fixed tr {
    display: flex;
  }
  .header-fixed th,
  .header-fixed td {
    width: 4em;
    padding: 0.2em;
  }
  td:nth-child(2),
  th:nth-child(2){
    /* tamaño de ID, Precio y Stock fijos (4em c/u) */
    width: calc(100% - 12em);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <body>
  <table class="header-fixed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope='col' class="id">ID</th>
      <th scope='col'>Producto</th>
      <th scope='col'>Precio</th>
      <th scope='col'>Stock</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>1</th>
      <td>Producto 1</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>13</th>
      <td>Producto 2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>13</th>
      <td>Producto 2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>13</th>
      <td>Producto 2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>13</th>
      <td>Producto 2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>13</th>
      <td>Producto 2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>13</th>
      <td>Producto 2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>13</th>
      <td>Producto 2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>13</th>
      <td>Producto 2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>13</th>
      <td>Producto 2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>13</th>
      <td>Producto 2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>13</th>
      <td>Producto 2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>13</th>
      <td>Producto 2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>13</th>
      <td>Producto 2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>13</th>
      <td>Producto 2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>13</th>
      <td>Producto 2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>13</th>
      <td>Producto 2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>13</th>
      <td>Producto 2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>13</th>
      <td>Producto 2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>13</th>
      <td>Producto 2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>13</th>
      <td>Producto 2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>13</th>
      <td>Producto 2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>21</th>
      <td>Producto 3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>21</th>
      <td>Producto 3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr><tr>
      <th scope='row'>21</th>
      <td>Producto 3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr><tr>
      <th scope='row'>21</th>
      <td>Producto 3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr><tr>
      <th scope='row'>21</th>
      <td>Producto 3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr><tr>
      <th scope='row'>21</th>
      <td>Producto 3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr><tr>
      <th scope='row'>21</th>
      <td>Producto 3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr><tr>
      <th scope='row'>21</th>
      <td>Producto 3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr><tr>
      <th scope='row'>21</th>
      <td>Producto 3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr><tr>
      <th scope='row'>21</th>
      <td>Producto 3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr><tr>
      <th scope='row'>21</th>
      <td>Producto 3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr><tr>
      <th scope='row'>21</th>
      <td>Producto 3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr><tr>
      <th scope='row'>21</th>
      <td>Producto 3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr><tr>
      <th scope='row'>21</th>
      <td>Producto 3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr><tr>
      <th scope='row'>21</th>
      <td>Producto 3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr><tr>
      <th scope='row'>21</th>
      <td>Producto 3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr><tr>
      <th scope='row'>21</th>
      <td>Producto 3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr><tr>
      <th scope='row'>21</th>
      <td>Producto 3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>...</th>
      <td>Producto ...</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class='bag'>
        <span class='badge badge-color'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: Lo estuve probando y cuando varía el ancho de algún **td** se desordena la tabla. Agrego **th / td:nth-child(2){}** para compensarlo. Lo solucioné poniéndole un ancho fijo a todas las columnas menos a la segunda que usa `calc()` para determinar el espacio que queda disponible y ocuparlo.

Comment: Si, en la columna producto tengo nombres de 10-20 caracteres, yo lo solucione con `.header-fixed thead th:nth-child(2),
.header-fixed tbody td:nth-child(2) {
 min-width: 8em;
 max-width: 400px;
}`. esta bien?

Comment: Creo que de esa manera puede variar el tamaño de la columna en distintas filas. Pero probalo y cualquier cosa avisá. Para mí, una buena solución, en este caso, es darles un tamaño fijo a las tres columnas que tienen una cantidad de caracteres mas o menos predecible; y darle el resto del espacio a la otra. Y si quisieras agregar otra columna con una cantidad variable de caracteres podrías usar **calc( (100% - 12em ) /2 )** por ejemplo.

Comment: De tu manera me quedo asi mira https://ibb.co/3czfv3z

Comment: Que raro, fijate en la consola del navegador si se está agregando algún estilo de otro lado. El **.header-fixed thead** tiene **width: 100%**?

Comment: Si usaste eso que dijiste en el comentario, probablemente venga de ahí el problema, porque al estar sobreescribiendo el layout de la tabla, no tiene manera de hacer coincidir el tamaño las columnas de distintas filas, por eso habría que usar **calc()** para darles a todas el mismo tamaño.

Comment: Comente mi codigo y utilize el tuyo. No tenia el 100%; se lo agregue y quedo asi https://ibb.co/4tYYD9b. Mira el codigo. https://ibb.co/TLPj4Zy

Comment: Probá comentando el anteúltimo bloque y fijate como queda. El **calc(... /2)** te decía que podías usarlo si agregabas otra columna. Te recomiendo dejarlo como está en la respuesta si no agregaste ninguna. En **.header-fixed th/td** debería ser **width** en vez de **min-width**.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95649/discussion-between-andres-gaibor-and-n-n).